# how to identify DISPLAY value of multiple hdmi ports of machine for cronjob

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, cron, hdmi

my current cronjob is this:

```
 * * * * *    DISPLAY=:0 python3 "/home/ubuntu/test.pyc"
```

This cronjob works fine with monitor connected on HDMI port 1 but when I change `DISPLAY=:1` then it does not display output on second HDMI port connected screen.

I want to redirect output of cronjob to second HDMI port connected screen but I dont know how to get the value or number of second HDMI port.

Answer (score 0):

Display numbers does not necessary relate to HDMI port numbers.
Please, read documentation here: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man7/X.7.html
Section "Display Names" first.